# Calculating grades with different weighted percentages and outputting a final grade in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I need to write a bash shell script that asks the user for their name and 4 test scores worth different percentages which then calculates their total grade and outputs their letter grade.

The values are as follows:

```
Assignments 30%
Midterm 30%
quiz 10%
Final 30%
```

I've tried multyplying my variables by (30/100) after theyve been read but I can not get bash to accept mupltiple lines of arithmetic. So far I'e only been able to add them all up and divide by 4. I'm lost at this point any help is appreciated

```sh
echo "What is your name?"
read name 
echo "What is your score on the Assignment?"
read s1 
echo "What is your score on the Quiz?"
read s2 
echo "What is your score on the Midterm Exam?"
read s3 
echo "What is your score on the Final Exam?"
read s4 


total=$(expr $s1 + $s2 + $s3 + $s4) 
avg=$(expr $total / 4) 


 if [ $avg -ge 80 ] 
 then 
  echo "$name's grade is an A"
 elif [ $avg -ge 70 ] 
 then 
         echo "$name's grade is a B" 
 elif [ $avg -ge 60 ] 
 then 
         echo "$name's grade is a C"
 elif [ $avg -ge 50 ] 
 then 
         echo "$names's grade is a D"
 else 
 echo "$name's grade is an F" 
 fi
```

Comment: You know bash is only capable of *integer* math. Use the `(( ... ))` arithmetic operators instead of `expr` (e.g. `total=$((s1 + s2 + s3 + s4))`). If you need floating point precision (to eliminate significant potential for rounding error), then use `bc` (installed on most distros) or use `awk` instead of bash. (to use percentages with *integer* math, first multiply everything by `100` and then divide by `100` at the very end)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things you can do following on from my comment above. First use the POSIX arithmetic operators `(( ... ))` instead of the ancient `expr`. Next, since bash only provides *integer* math, in order to work with your percentages, you must multiply the percentages by `100` and then divide by `100` to obtain the `total`. You don't divide by `4`, your percentages already account for weighting scores to arrive at 100%. Further, in bash and then you must rely on a floating point utility like `bc` to handle all floating point calculations, including the division to arrive at your `avg`.

However, that alone will not remove the rounding error when you go to compare `avg` in your `if then elif ... else` statements (e.g. treating `79.9` as `79`). Using `bc` to obtain `79.9` you still need a way to properly handle *rounding* to obtain `80` from `79.5` (or better) and `79` for anything less than `79.5` but greater than or equal to `78.5`.

Thankfully `printf -v` provides a convenient way to store the results of a conversion as a variable and handle the rounding since it uses the the C-print conversion logic. For example, to save the results of `avg` converted by `bc` and then properly rounded (saved in the variable name `rounded`) you could do:

```
total=$((s1 * 30 + s2 * 30 + s3 * 10 + s4 * 30))
avg=$((total / 100))  ## not used but saved for output demonstration below
printf -v rounded "%.0f" $(printf "scale=2; $total/100\n" | bc)
```

Putting it altogether you could do:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "What is your name?"
read name 
echo "What is your score on the Assignment?"
read s1 
echo "What is your score on the Quiz?"
read s2 
echo "What is your score on the Midterm Exam?"
read s3 
echo "What is your score on the Final Exam?"
read s4 

total=$((s1 * 30 + s2 * 30 + s3 * 10 + s4 * 30))
avg=$((total / 100)) 
printf -v rounded "%.0f" $(printf "scale=2; $total/100\n" | bc)

if [ "$rounded" -ge 80 ] 
then 
    echo "$name's grade is an A"
elif [ "$rounded" -ge 70 ] 
then 
    echo "$name's grade is a B" 
elif [ "$rounded" -ge 60 ] 
then 
    echo "$name's grade is a C"
elif [ "$rounded" -ge 50 ] 
then 
    echo "$names's grade is a D"
else 
    echo "$name's grade is an F" 
fi
```

To confirm the rounding his handled properly, you can add a simply `printf` following saving `rounded`, for example add:

```
printf "\ntotal: %d\navg  : %d\nrounded avg: %d\n\n" \
        "$total" "$avg" "$rounded"
```

Then to confirm, enter scores that would result in a number that if not rounded properly would result in a `"B"` instead of an `"A"` (which you liberally give at a score of `80`), e.g.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash student.sh
What is your name?
John
What is your score on the Assignment?
78
What is your score on the Quiz?
80
What is your score on the Midterm Exam?
81
What is your score on the Final Exam?
81

total: 7980
avg  : 79
rounded avg: 80

John's grade is an A
```

**Using a `case` Statement**

You may also want to consider eliminating your long chain of `if then elif then elif then ...` statement with a simple `case ... esac` statement that will greatly clean things up. For example you can replace the entire collection of `if then elif ... else` with

```
printf "%s's grade is an '" "$name"
case "$rounded" in
    100 | [89]? ) echo "A'";;
             7? ) echo "B'";;
             6? ) echo "C'";;
             5? ) echo "D'";;
             *  ) echo "F'";;
esac
```

**Example Use/Output With `case`**

```
$ bash student.sh
What is your name?
John
What is your score on the Assignment?
78
What is your score on the Quiz?
80
What is your score on the Midterm Exam?
80
What is your score on the Final Exam?
80

total: 7940
avg  : 79
rounded avg: 79

John's grade is an 'B'
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Thank you so much that's exactly how I needed the percentage scores to be handled  I don't know why I did not think to multiply them then divide the total by 100. Anyways I really appreciate the help and you definitely showed me a better way to do calculations in bash.

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with your scripting. Bash is a fantastic shell, but there is a LOT to learn. Have fun with it.